# Does this kanji stamp actually mean "harmony"?

Tags: writing-identification

[image: unknown kanji on rubber stamp]

I was given a rubber stamp (image above) that supposedly means "harmony" but I suspect it doesn't. Can anyone confirm the meaning or tell me its real one?

Comment: You may look for the upside-down version of that character next time you go to a Chinese restaurant in your country and ask a clerk there what it means.  https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search;_ylt=A2RhYka.8_5c4RAAx9iJBtF7?p=%E7%A6%8F%E3%80%80%E9%80%86%E3%81%95%E3%81%BE&fr=top_ga1_sa&ei=UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the 福{ふく} character which means "good fortune"